# How do I connect my Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tab to a hard wired broadband point (no wifi available)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have moved into student accommodation which only has hard wired broadband. Please can anyone tell me how I can connect my Galaxy 10.1 tablet to the internet via the wall point provided?

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  The Tab doesn't have an ethernet jack and doesn't support it anyways.

If you don't want to get yourself a wireless router, you can set up a WiFi network through a computer with a WiFi card.  There's [a guide on LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot) on this for Windows 7.  The basics:

1. Connect your PC to the wired network
2. Create an ad-hoc network on the PC (you'll want to encrypt it)
3. Enable ICS (Internet Connection Sharing)
4. Connect the Tab to the WiFi network broadcast by the PC

If you have trouble getting the PC portion to work, you should ask how to get it working on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) since they handle PC stuff like this.

Comment: Many thanks Matthew - I'll look into getting a wireless router first as I don't have a PC available.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Matthew said I'd also suggest a wifi router but use it as a repeater, any cheap wifi router will do just turn off DHCP, use as AP, change the gateway to something other than 192.168.x.x and probably check the option to use as a LAN extension.

Answer (score 0):

There are some adapters that will provide yu with a USB port, where you could connect a USB-based network adapter. however, I had no chance with the one I had. I installed an access point in my wired setup, and it worked fine. Mine is a D-LINK DAP-1350.