# Generic approach to get Ethernet working on android

Tags: custom-roms, networking, ethernet

Is there a generalised approach to getting Ethernet cable networking to work on (preferably) recent Android versions with minimum fiddling?

I've looked at other similar questions but they focus on pre-existing devices, specific Ethernet adapters and/or specific ROMs.

For example, I have found that Nexus 7 (2013) with the ResurrectionRemix ROM (Android 7.1.2) worked with a generic noname Ethernet (powered) adapter from aliexpress when connected through an OTG cable and with the USB RNDIS selected in Options > Developer Settings > Default USB Configuration. Connecting power to the ethernet adapter, the OTG cable and the RNDIS setting was all that was required.

With more recent android devices and newer Android versions I could not identify a successful combination of rom+adapter+device+[kernel].

Given that I am willing to root a device and/or buy a specific combination of compatible android device + compatible ethernet adapter, what are some known configurations that work out-of-the-box with minimal extra configuration? Any hints, suggestions or guidelines in this regard?

Alternatively, is there a 'generic' package with USB-Ethernet drivers that could be flashed for widely supported ROMs (such as lineageos) that [in combination with a custom kernel or without] would provide Ethernet connectivity?

And finally, in case if the official AOSP/LineageOS/etc repos have this functionality but it is not enabled by default, what would be the steps to build a ROM such as lineageos or AOSP with all possible Ethernet and USB-Ethernet modules enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225643/how-to-make-ethernet-work-on-android-over-otg)

Comment: I _did_ read that answer before posting this question. That answer focuses on what technically needs to be done on an android device in order to get ethernet up. This question is specifically about how to _avoid_ having to do all those steps manually, and instead pick a combination of device+adapter+rom+kernel that just works (as in the example I provided), or how to build/mod a rom to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

- [Mokee 11 ROM experimental](https://download.mokeedev.com/) (Android 11, apparently a fork of lineageos) and xiaomi.eu roms contain the required ethernet drivers that happened to work with two USB-C to Ethernet adapters that I tried. The USB-C version of the ethernet adapter works on a rooted mipad4 tablet OOTB without any extra actions required. The USB-A version only worked with an intermediary USB hub + USB-A to USB-C dongle. When connected via a USB hub the network connection will only appear after rebooting the device with the cable plugged in or after issuing in the terminal `su` followed by `dumpsys ethernet`.