# How do rndis0 and eth0 interfaces get set up?

Tags: networking, tethering, ethernet

In a normal installation, looking at `ifconfig` (or `ip`) in `adb shell`, there are no `rndis0` or `eth0` interfaces set up. Once USB tethering or ethernet tethering is enabled, they show up.

With my GNU/Linux hat on, I thought there is some module loading and `udev` happening in the background, but clearly, that's not the case.

Can anyone explain what is happening in the background and how can this be replicated via shell commands?

Comment: Thoroughly explained in [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526).

Comment: Thanks @IrfanLatif , looks good at first glance, will dive into it soon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225643/how-to-make-ethernet-work-on-android-over-otg)

Comment: @IrfanLatif got a bit lost in the translation there. I am not sure that applies to Android 11 (AOSP/ArrowOS), for example I can't create a /system/etc/init/custom.rc due to read-only file system. On short term, do you know the quick command to enable ethernet tethering? I found the one for usb (svc usb setFunctions rndis), but I need to use the Android 11 newly introduced ethernet tethering.

Comment: Go system-less using something like Magisk modules. // No I'm not aware of quick command. Sorry.