# Change network interface name in persistent way on Android

Tags: root-access, networking, system, kernel

Is it possible to change the name of a network interface in an Android 11 rooted system making the change persistent? I am not looking for just renaming the interface after the boot, I want to change the kernel provided interface name, so that this change is persistent after reboots.

In my specific case, I want to rename an USB interface that should be assigned an IP address; the interface name is `usb0` and I want to call it `eth0`.

```
# ip link sh
...
usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225643/how-to-make-ethernet-work-on-android-over-otg)

Comment: Well, I'm writing _precisely_ because I cannot understand the step in which the task that I need is performed in that link...

Comment: okay good luck..